# Xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed (Unable to add 1080p resolution to second monitor)

Tags: display, display-resolution, xrandr, external-monitor

I had Ubuntu 16 and I was able to add the 1080p resolution for my second monitor (VGA1) but after I installed Ubuntu 17, I get the error when I want to output the new resolution: `xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed`.

Here's what I did:

```
$ cvt 1920 1080 60.0
# 1920x1080 59.96 Hz (CVT 2.07M9) hsync: 67.16 kHz; pclk: 173.00 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
$ xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
$ xrandr --addmode XWAYLAND0 1920x1080_60.00
$ xrandr --output XWAYLAND0 --mode 1920x1080_60.00
xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed
```

I've searched a lot, but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: I think I saw some where were it was suggested use of the login option for `xorg` at the login screen!

Comment: @George what do you mean exactly? How to use that login option?

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/157465/349837) help.

Comment: what's your Xorg version? `Xorg -version`?

Answer (score -2):

Please open the following file and remove the # (comment) :

```
/etc/gdm/custom.conf or/etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

The line to remove the comment :

```
#WaylandEnable=false
```

Restart the GDM service and try the following command :

```
xrandr
```

This should remove the WAYLAND and start showing the VGA or HDMI depending on your display port