# Second screen will not increase resolution

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, dell, hdmi, display-resolution

I have two identical QHD moniters both connected using HDMI to a thunderbolt dock.

One screen is running at 2560x1440 as expected. The second cannot go higher than 1440x900.

If I increase it then screen 1 will loose connection and turn off, I can run 2 screens but with one at full res the other at a max of 1400x900.

I have tried using xrandr to set the resolution but this causes the same effect of disconnecting the other monitor and throws the below error:

```
xrandr: Configure crtc 1 failed
```

I have worked through each item, both HDMI ports on the dock can support the resolution so it isn't the screens, cables, or dock. Which just leaves the laptop grahpics card or a setting in Ubuntu which I need to change.

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on a Dell XPS 13 which has Intel Iris Plus Graphics so should support 2 QHD screens. The dock can support 2 HDMI screens at 4k.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/157465/1001338).Does that help you?

Comment: @ParsaMousavi Sadly tried that. It might have something to do with additional drivers but I have played with them and still no luck.